# How do I deserialize a Player's inventory?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Here's my serialization method. How would I go about deserializing/loading it later on?

*`invs` is my `inventories.yml` `FileConfiguration` variable.*

```
public void action(Player p){
    PlayerInventory i = p.getInventory();
    int slot = 0;
    for(ItemStack item : i){
        Map<String, Object> itemS = item.serialize();
        if(Main.invs.get(p.getName() + ".inventory.slot." + slot) == null){
            Main.invs.createSection(p.getName()+ ".inventory.slot." + slot);
        }
        Main.invs.set(p.getName() + ".inventory.slot." + slot, itemS);
        slot = slot + 1;
    }
    slot = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public PlayerInventory deserializeInventory(Player p) {
    PlayerInventory inv = p.getInventory();
    for(int slot = 0; slot < 36 /*Size of inventory */; slot++){
        //Removes any existing item from the inventory.
        inv.clear(slot);

        Object itemTemp = Main.invs.get(p.getName() + ".inventory.slot." + slot);
        if (itemTemp == null) { //Skip null values.
            continue;
        }
        if (!(itemTemp instanceof ItemStack)) {
            //Might want to do an error message, but for now just ignore this.
            continue;
        }
        ItemStack item = (ItemStack) itemTemp;
        inv.setItem(slot, item);
    }
    return inv;
}
```

As a side note, I strongly recommend changing your serialization method to this:

```
public void action(Player p){
    PlayerInventory i = p.getInventory();
    for(int slot = 0; slot < 36 /*Size of inventory */; slot++){
        ItemStack item = i.getItem(slot);
        if (item == null || item.getType() == Material.AIR) { //Do nothing.
            continue;
        }
        Map<String, Object> itemS = item.serialize();
        if(Main.invs.get(p.getName() + ".inventory.slot." + slot) == null){
            Main.invs.createSection(p.getName()+ ".inventory.slot." + slot);
        }
        Main.invs.set(p.getName() + ".inventory.slot." + slot, itemS);
    }
}
```

Doing this will preserve the location of the items, and also adds a few error checking things.

Comment: I've actually had an error with the || (OR comparison) part, do you think this would work?

http://pastebin.com/UjZkLeHK

Comment: That should work, and I'm editing my post to fix it.  I've got no idea how I messed up that || part, but it's clearly a mistake.